# Http client with multiple goroutines and a different proxy per request

Tags: http, go

Consider that I have an `http.Client` where multiple goroutines are making `GET` request using the same http client, my problem is I want to guarantee that each get request is done through a different Proxy.

I couldn't find a way to achieve that in the `net/http/Transport` docs, is my best bet using a pool of http clients, or modify the [`go/src/net/http/transport.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/transport.go) to receive a function that will return a proxy to be used per request?

thanks to JimB turns out its as simple as something like

```
client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(GetProxyUrl())
        return proxyUrl, err
    }}}
```

Comment: The Transport.Proxy field is already a function that returns the proxy per request.

Comment: @JimB I don't know how I missed that, thanks a lot put your comment in an answer if you like